# Does converting from Pix to Bitmap modify the pix

Tags: android, bitmap, leptonica

I have an Android AsyncTask that repeatedly converts Pix to Bitmap using Leptonica library's `ReadFile.readBitmap(bitmap)` method.I am performing this conversion after any image processing operation is completed and a Pix object is obtained from it.

I find that the result of OCR using Tesseract is better when I do not convert Bitmap to Pix.However,I have not converted Pix to Bitmap in any of the operations.A typical cycle looks like:

```
 mOperation=CONVERT_TO_8;
 Pix pix2=convertOperation(pix);
 mOperation=PIX_TO_BITMAP;
 Bitmap bitmap2=convertPixToBitmap(pix2);
 publishProgress(bitmap2);
 mOperation=SCALE_PIX;//next operation...
```

So,what do I have to do if I would like to maintain the quality of the OCR result while displaying Bitmap as progress.

Answer (score 0):

I still do not know the answer to this question but it probably is yes.I used the deep copy method available in Leptonica to copy the Pix to a temporary Pix object before converting it to a Bitmap.It works just fine now:

```
 Pix temp=pix.copy();
```